# R plot based on another factor

Tags: r, plot

I have a set of data looks like this:

**CHROM POS      GT DIFF**

**chr01 integer  AG integer**

**chr01 integer  GA integer**

**chr02 integer  CG integer**

..

**chr22 integer  GT integer**

**chrX integer   TC integer**

I want to plot POS(x-axis) vs DIFF(y-axis), and I want to group x-axis based on the level of CHROM.

Below is a sample plot I have only for chr01.
I want to have chr02 ... chrX in this plot as well to the right of chr01.
[image]

My code is:

```
my.key <- list(space="right",
           border=T,
           cex.title=1.2,
           title="Legend",
           size=10,
           text=levels(GT),
           fill=T)

xyplot(data$DIFF[data$CHROM=="chr01"]~data$POS[data$CHROM=="chr01"],
   xlab = "chr01 -- LCMT0001",
   ylab = "Distance -- LCMT0001",
   col=GT,
   group=GT,
   auto.key = my.key,
   pch=16,
   scales=list(
     x = list(alternating=F,tick.number = 8),
     y = list(log=10,tick.number=11))
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `ggplot`:

```
# some sample data
df <- data.frame(CHROM = 1:4,
                 POS = 1:5,
                 GT = sample(c("ac", "ag", "at"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                 DIFF= sample(1:100))


ggplot(data = df, aes(x = POS, y = DIFF, colour = GT)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~ CHROM) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear that you found my answer useful!

Comment: I have another problem. Since I have very large variance of DIFF, and I dont want to scale with log(DIFF), how do I change the axis as 0,10,100,1000, and so on? Thanks!

Comment: And is there a way to have unique x-axis for each group(i.e. 1,2,3,4,5 for group1, and 1,2,3 for group2)

Comment: Check `scale_y_log10` [**here**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html)

Comment: ...and `facet_grid(..., scales = "free_x"` [**here**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_grid.html)

Comment: Hi, for this plot, I said I wanted to spread out the x axis before (used "free_x", but now I wanted to kind of like scale the panel for each region by the range of POS. Is that possible? (i.e. if panel 1 has max POS of 3, then dont show 4,5 on the axis but still keep the width of panel 1)